# error in if() argument is of length zero in R

Tags: r, if-statement, arguments, zero

This is the code

`

> region<-"ARLINGTON"
>
> data<-read.csv("city_markets.csv")
>
> for(i in 1:length(data[[1]])){
>
> if(grep(region,as.character(data[[3]][i]),ignore.case=TRUE)==1){
>
> ```
> for(j in 1:length(data)){
>     write(data[[j]][i],"analyzed.txt",append=TRUE)
>   }   
> }
> ```
>
> }
>   `

now what i'm trying to do here is I'm accessing the csv's column(3rd one) and comparing it with the region specified! i keep getting the error

> Error in if (grep(region, as.character(data[[3]][i]), ignore.case = TRUE) ==  :
>
> argument is of length zero

Comment: try with `grepl` instead of `grep`

Comment: Or add `length()` for `grep` result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detail a bit my comment and @Adii_ 's :

when you use `grep`, the result is the "position" of elements that fulfill the condition... so "nothing" if there is no match (hence the error message).

Using `grepl`, you'll get TRUE or FALSE, which you can use in your `if` statement.

As for `length(grep(...))`, the result will be `0` if there is no match, corresponding to `FALSE` for the `if` statement, or a positive integer (`1` in your case because you're testing only one element), if there is a match, corresponding to `TRUE` for the `if` statement.

Comment: thanx CathG for the suggestion of using grepl. but for some reason, i found the solution by removing indexes from my grepl(or grep) command.

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem:

```
region<-"ARLINGTON"

data<-read.csv("city_markets.csv")

for(i in 1:length(data[[1]])){

a<-as.character(data[[3]][i])

if(grepl(region,a,ignore.case=TRUE)){
for(j in 1:length(data)){
    write(data[[j]][i],"analyzed.txt",append=TRUE)
  }   
}

} `
```