# Error in if condition {: argument is of length zero

Tags: r, while-loop

I have a R dataframe `df` as given below:

```
ID        End_week
2500076   1223
6801102   1325
6801282   1308
6803252   1426
9882106   1426
9894112   1217
```

I want to insert a new column `status` with 0/1 values - 1 if End_week equals 1426 and 0 otherwise. Final output should look like this:

```
ID        End_week   Status
2500076   1223       0
6801102   1325       0
6801282   1308       0
6803252   1426       1
9882106   1426       1
9894112   1217       0
```

I wrote a while loop as given below:

```
while(i<=length(df$End_week)) {
  if(df$End_week[i]==1426) {
    status[i] <- 1
  } else {
    status[i] <- 0
  }
  i=i+1
}
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (df$End_week[i] == 1426) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I know that the question has been asked before and so I [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350636/r-argument-is-of-length-zero-in-if-statement) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307139/error-in-if-while-condition-argument-is-of-length-zero) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015180/error-in-if-argument-is-of-length-zero-in-r), but didn't find them helpful in my scenario. I checked for any `NA` values in `End_week` column and there aren't any. Can someone suggest a way out?

Comment: `df$Status <- ifelse(End_week == 1426, 1, 0)` or `df$Status <- ifelse(End_week == '1426', 1, 0)` depending on class of df$Status

Comment: Or just convert the logical vector to `integer` i.e. `as.integer(End_week == 1426)`

Comment: @CPak - that's so cool. I didn't know this trick. And it works for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest researching  dataframe subsetting as your missing out on a substantial benefit of r.

```
df$Status <- 0
df$Status[df$End_week == 1426] <- 1
```

Comment: This is also very helpful. Thanks!